# Figcaption leaves unwanted line of space?

Tags: css, html

I'm making a figcaption to an image, and I want to link that to a seperate pdf document.
Can be seen at http://cascade.webuda.com/collection.html where is says 2013 cascade luce catalog.

Right there, there is an unwanted line of space which no matter what I do I cannot remove it.

I checked all of my CSS and I couldn't figure out the problem.
Is there a way to do this? (Preferably not using anything but HTML5 and CSS?)

Answer (score 3):

You have padding on h2 and p inside your figcaption.

```
figcaption h2, figcaption p {
         padding: 0px;
         margin: 0px;
}
```